# passing (pointer to UInt8 array) and accessing the array in Objective-C

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to work with array of UInt8 but I am not sure how to do this correctly...

This is my code:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    __strong id * myArray; //private byte[] myArray;  <- Java code
}
@property   (nonatomic,readwrite) __strong id * myArray;
@end
```

This is a method in MyClass:

```
-(int) getArray: (__strong id *) bufferTmp {

    NSString* aString = @"theString";
    int bytes  = aString.length;

    //now I need to fill the passed in array with the chars of the String
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
            char c = [aString characterAtIndex:i];
            ??? bufferTmp[i] = (UInt8)c;   <----- what to write here?
        }
return bytes;
}
```

This is how I plan to call this method to fill the myBuffer:

```
UInt8 myBuffer[10000];
[xxx read: myBuffer];       <-      how to do this correctly ?????
```

This is the equivalent working Java code:

```
public int getArray(byte[] bufferTmp) {
    String theString = "theString";
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        char c = theString.charAt(i);
        bufferTmp[i] = (byte) c;
        }
     return bytes;

 }
```

And this is how I call this method in Java:

```
 byte[] myBuffer = new byte[10000]; 
 int n = read(myBuffer);
```

Comment: Why are you going to the trouble of working with `bufferTmp[]` if it has no bearing on the 'outcome of the function?

Comment: do you mean in Java - sorry this was a typo, I corrected that. Basically the method just fills the passed in byte array with the chars of the string...

Comment: I do not understand your "equivalent working Java code": the `msg` argument is not used, it returns a value but the return type is `void` ...

Comment: yes, it returns the length of the buffer as int, I corrected that above in the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, you can use `NSData` objects as byte buffer, and `dataUsingEncoding` to obtain a byte representation of the string:

```
NSString *aString = @"theString";
NSData *myBuffer = [aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

const char *bytes = [myBuffer bytes]; // pointer to the bytes in the buffer
NSUInteger count = [myBuffer length]; // number of bytes in the buffer
```